# I don't understand this mistake in R: In pt(-abs(tVal), fDF) : NaNs produced

Tags: r

I'm doing a mixed model with the function lme:
The code is:

```
modelomixto1<-lme(fixed= LargoCorola~Tratamiento*Rango, random = ~1|Rango/Poblacion/Codigo.FG, 
                  na.action=na.exclude, data = df1)
```

I think the code is correct, but the result gives me a warnning message:

```
Warning message:
In pt(-abs(tVal), fDF) : NaNs produced
```

I'm not any expert in R, so I can't understand what is wrong.
Thanks in advance